# Spring : Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field, CrudRepository extended interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, crud, autowired

I have extended `CrudRepository<ClassName, Id>` in user defined Interface, but while trying to inject using `@Autowired` i am getting following given below error :

> creating bean with name 'helloController': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'danCorePrivateRepository'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'com.sgcorp.repository.DanCorePrivateRepository' available: expected
>   at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

HelloController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {
    @Autowired
    private DanCorePrivateRepository danCorePrivateRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/service", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String selectService(){  
        String result = "<html>";   
        result += "<div>"+danCorePrivateRepository.findAll()+"</div>";
        return result+ "</html>";
    }
}
```

DanCorePrivateRepository.java (user defined interface)

```
public interface DanCorePrivateRepository extends CrudRepository<DanaModel, String> {

}
```

Kindly suggest why its not @Autowired properly?

*Note: with some other project it was working.*

Comment: where is this class `DAnCorePrivateRepository` ? is it under component scna? Show the package structure of your class

Comment: DAnCorePrivateRepository  this is interface only i am using SpringBoot only no need for Component scan for that,            i have used  @SpringBootApplication annotation, that is implicit Component Scan.

Comment: Make sure `DanCorePrivateRepository` is located in the same package in  `@SpringBootApplication` application class or it subpackages.

Comment: Add @Repository on DanCorePrivateRepository interface

Answer (score 5):

Please add the @EnableJpaRepositories annotation on top on your configuration class.  This @EnableJpaRepositories annotation has the basePackages or basePackageClasses attribute, through which you can specify the packages (which are annotated with @Repository) to be scanned by Spring Data JPA.

Answer (score -2):

I think you have missed annotations `@RepositoryRestResource` and `@Repository` on your user defined Interface `DanCorePrivateRepository`. You have to mark it as follows -

```
@Repository
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface DanCorePrivateRepository extends CrudRepository<DanaModel, String> {

}
```

`@RepositoryRestResource` annotation will direct Spring to create RESTful endpoints for your repository.

Comment: Still same Error Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'helloController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'danCorePrivateRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.sgcorp.repository.DanCorePrivateRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

Comment: Try and add `@Repository` as well to your interface